# How to pass username into form that sends data to database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I am trying to pass username to database through form:

```
[insert_php]
$current_user= wp_get_current_user();
$id= $current_user->user_login; 
[/insert_php]


<input type="hidden" name="id" value="[insert_php]$id[/insert_php]">
```

But it doesn't get through, the rest of visible inputs do go through though.

So my question is:

is this the correct structure:

```
$id= ...;
```

and then make an input in form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $id; ?>">
```

Should it work or am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
global $id;
```

Declaring it globally should be the fix.

Comment: I do have a form and it works properly, only hidden value doesn't go through

Comment: What are you trying to set $id equal to?

Comment: username value in wordpress, when I echo $id before the form it prints out the value so its not empty

Comment: I already have $id setup before form, I just need to pass it through the form, but it doesn't work

Comment: Declare the variable globally. Look at my answer